# Quarkus Hibernate Reactive Panache, No current Vertx context found on some database wrights

Tags: quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging, hibernate-reactive

Using Quarkus hibernate Reactive Panache and the quarkiverse.reactivemessaging.http dependency trying to wright some data from a websocket connection into the database.

Works as expected but getting the following error on sum attempts.

`Failed to process incoming web socket message.: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current Vertx context found`

Appears to be somewhat a random though request done together do appear to succeed.

```
  @Inject
  Mutiny.SessionFactory sf;

  @WithSession
  @Incoming("collector")
  Uni<Void> collect(final String text) {

    Mss msg = new Mss(text);
    return sf.withTransaction(session -> msg.persistAndFlush()).replaceWithVoid();

  }
```

Or

```
  @WithSession
  @Incoming("collector")
  Uni<Mss> collect(final String text) {
    Mss msg = new Mss(text);
    return msg.persist();
  }
```

Tried running on quarkus 2 but same issue as before

Edit getting the same effect with

```
@WithTransaction
@Incoming("collector")
public Uni<Void> collect(final String text) {
  System.out.println(text);
  return Uni.createFrom().voidItem();
}
```

Comment: Hey, I'm running into the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Maybe this helps: You need to annotate your `@Incoming` methods with `@ActivateRequestContext`